PDFBox fill field - text squashed/compressed
I fill fields in a pdf with com.openhtmltopdf and org.apache.pdfbox.
[INFO] +- com.openhtmltopdf:openhtmltopdf-core:jar:1.0.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.openhtmltopdf:openhtmltopdf-pdfbox:jar:1.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:xmpbox:jar:2.0.24:compile

This is my code:
private void populateFieldsWithData(Map<String, String> data, PDAcroForm acroForm, List<PDField> fields) throws IOException {
    data.forEach((key, value) -> {
        PDField field = acroForm.getField(key);
        acroForm.getFieldTree().iterator().forEachRemaining(pdField -> {
            if (pdField.getFullyQualifiedName().equals(key)) {
                try {
                    field.setValue(value);
                    field.setReadOnly(true);
                    fields.add(pdField);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    acroForm.flatten();
}

The problem is that the text in the generated pdf is squashed/compressed.
I tried removing acroForm.flatten();. If I do and I click on the text in the generated pdf the text is adjusted and looks normal. But when I click elsewhere in the generated pdf the text goes back to beeing squashed/compressed.
I have tried adding these before acroForm.flatten();. Both and separate but that doesn't help.
acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);
acroForm.refreshAppearances();

This is what the generated field looks like:

This is what the field looks like if I enter the same text manually in Acrobat Reader:


Please share your PDF and tell what PDFBox version you are using, and add screenshots. Make sure you're using a current version, i.e. 2.0.31 or 3.0.2. I have spent you an upvote to counter the downvote.

Thank you! I have added version information and screenshots. I will try to share the pdf tomorrow.

2.0.24 is definitely too old. Please retry with the current version.

As you can see in the dependency tree I get pdfbox through openhtmltopdf. I use the latest version of openhtmltopdf. I have tried to update pdfbox to 2.0.31 but that didn't help. openhtmltopdf is not compatible with pdfbox 3.0.2.

The problem is related to the pdf. Other pdfs works fine. BUT IText, which was the previous pdf generation library we used, can generate the pdf I'm having problems with. I have also tried to remove openhtmltopdf and only use pdfbox 3.0.2 but I get the same resuls as with pdfbox 2.0.24.
